# Why my form item cannot be clear by a new instance of an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a6csul) is my code.

It is a form for user input data.

Users can click on the 'Add Row' to add a new row for input data.

The `useEffect` function simulate getting data from the database.

**Expected result:**

When users click on the 'Save' button, I want to clear all data input rows,

and remain an empty data input row.

**Actual result:**

When users click on the 'Save' button, all data input rows are cleared,

however, some fields in the remaining data input row are not cleared.

Here is the function that handles the "save" button event:

```
let saveToDb=async(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let incident = new Incident();
  incident.catId=categoryOptionList[0].props.value;
  incident.systemId=systemOptionList[0].props.value;
  setIncidentDataList([incident]);
}
```

When the button is clicked, I instantiate a new instance of `Incident`object, and
set it to the `IncidentDataList` state variable, unfortunately, only the first 3 fields data are cleared, the rest fields are not.

I don't know why.

Would you help to fix the problem?

Comment: In you code the setIncidentDataList is reset the values for Incident object but not for IncidentDataList

Comment: I think you are binding with wrong variable value={incidentList.briefDesc} this should be value={incident.briefDesc}

Comment: Here is the changed code link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jhwxay?file=src%2FInputIncident.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just posting answer here for closure** [Working link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jhwxay)

The reason it was not clearing is due to wrong binding. Correct binding should be

**value={incident.briefDesc}**

[image]